# Error: 429 Too Many Requests while downloading deno imports

Tags: docker, deno

I am using deno with docker `hayd/alpine-deno` image and `denon` watching for file changes. When I build the container I get `429 Too Many Requests` importing the `std` dependencies:

```
...

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/int.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/map.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/merge.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/nil.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/omap.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/pairs.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/seq.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/set.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/str.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/timestamp.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/binary.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/bool.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/float.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/int.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/map.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/merge.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/nil.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/omap.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/pairs.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/seq.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/set.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/str.ts

Download https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/timestamp.ts

error: Import 'https://deno.land/std@0.54.0/encoding/_yaml/type/timestamp.ts' failed: 429 Too Many Requests
```

My external dependencies are in `deps.ts` which has the following imports:

```
export { Application, Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'
export { connect } from 'https://deno.land/x/redis/mod.ts'
```

There are no other external dependencies apart from the ones denon imports.

Dockerfile I use to run it:

```
FROM hayd/alpine-deno:1.0.1

ENV DENO_DIR /cache

EXPOSE 4000

WORKDIR /app/

COPY . .

RUN deno install --allow-read --allow-run --allow-write -f --unstable https://deno.land/x/denon/denon.ts
RUN deno cache src/deps.ts

ENTRYPOINT ["/root/.deno/bin/denon"]

CMD ["run", "--allow-net", "src/mod.ts"]
```

It appears many of the files are downloaded (or attempted to download, failed and retried) multiple times. This doesn't always happen, but often enough to break build automation. Has anyone had a similar issue? Is it an issue with caching the imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it an issue with caching the imports?

No, caching has nothing to do with it.

It seems `deno.land` has rate limiting, and you're exceeding those limits. What you can do is use github directly which most likely will have much higher limits.

For Denon use

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denosaurs/denon/master/denon.ts
```

---

You can also change your code dependencies:

Change `https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts` with `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oakserver/oak/master/mod.ts`

and for `redis` you should use `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keroxp/deno-redis/master/mod.ts`

https://deno.land/x is nothing else but a URL rewriting server, so in the end, you're actually pulling from Github.

> deno.land/x is a URL rewriting service for Deno scripts. The basic
>   format of code URLs is
>   https://deno.land/x/MODULE_NAME@BRANCH/SCRIPT.ts. If you leave out the
>   branch, it will default to the module’s default branch, usually
>   master.

---

You should use tagged releases instead of `master` otherwise your docker image won't have always the same Oak code.

For `v4.0.0`

```
export { Application, Router } from 'https://github.com/oakserver/oak/blob/v4.0.0/mod.ts'
export { connect } from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keroxp/deno-redis/v0.10.1/mod.ts
```

Comment: Thank you. Although some of the dependencies still import from deno.land, changing my own imports seems to be enough to fix the throttling issues for now.

Answer (score 0):

Deno package manager, pretty new. I check, Deno team still working on optimization.

Use pika, better support.

https://www.pika.dev/docs/

OR:

https://denopkg.com/

**denopkg sample:**

```
import { opn } from 'https://denopkg.com/hashrock/deno-opn/opn.ts'

opn('https://denopkg.com')
```